# Creating a prefix route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I want to create URLs of the form `/suffix-<slug>` with rails but I can't see how to map that on the `routes.rb`, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `resources :books, path: '/prefix-books'` ?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean Not really. I want that the create method in the controllers maps the `/object/<id>` view to `/prefix-<id>` or `/prefix-<slug>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to achieve that is to consider the prefix as part of the id and then handle removing it in the controller:

routes.js

```
# Only for one place
post '/:id' , to: 'books#create', id: /prefix-.*/

# Same format in multiple places
constraints(id: /prefix-.*/) do
  post '/:id' , to: 'books#create'
  ...
  # Works with resources as well
  resources 'objects'
end
```

Controller

```
def create
  params[:id].slice! "prefix-"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Dude, Thanks!, it really helped